# Adding users to roles in ASP.Net Identity with EF 6 causes new roles and users to be created

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, asp.net-identity, ef-core-6.0

I have hit a wall on this and hope someone else has the answer, I created a Blazor app with Identity this is what my `dbContext` looks like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, string, 
    AppUserClaim,AppUserRole,AppUserLogin,AppRoleClaim,AppUserToken>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
       
        builder.Entity<AppUser>().ToTable("Users");
     
        builder.Entity<AppUser>().Property(x => x.FirstName).IsRequired();
        builder.Entity<AppUser>().Property(x => x.LastName).IsRequired();
        builder.Entity<AppUser>().Property(x => x.LastLoginDate);
        builder.Entity<AppUser>().HasMany(x => x.Roles).WithOne(x=>x.User).HasForeignKey(x=>x.UserId).IsRequired();

        builder.Entity<AppUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles").HasOne(c => c.Role).WithMany(c => c.UserRoles).HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);

        builder.Entity<AppRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        builder.Entity<AppRole>().Property(x => x.Description);
        builder.Entity<AppRole>().HasMany(x => x.UserRoles).WithOne(e => e.Role).HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId).IsRequired();
        builder.Entity<AppRole>().HasMany(x => x.RoleClaims).WithOne(e=>e.Role).HasForeignKey(x=>x.RoleId).IsRequired();
        
        builder.Entity<AppRoleClaim>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
        builder.Entity<AppRoleClaim>().HasOne(x => x.Role);

        builder.Entity<AppUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");            
    }
}
```

And in my `program.cs`, I have this code:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<RoleManager<AppRole>>();
```

Here are my Identity classes:

```
public class AppRole:IdentityRole
{ 
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole>? UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppRoleClaim>? RoleClaims { get; set; }

    public AppRole()
    {
    }
}

public class AppRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<string>
{
    public virtual AppRole Role { get; set; }

    public AppRoleClaim()
    {
        Role = new AppRole();
    }
}

public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public byte[]? Photo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public AppUser()
    {
        FirstName = "";
        LastName = "";
        Roles = new List<AppUserRole>(); 
    }
}

public class AppUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
{
}

public class AppUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>
{
}

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRole Role { get; set; }

    public AppUserRole()
    {
        User = new AppUser();
        Role = new AppRole();
    }
}

public class AppUserToken : IdentityUserToken<string>
{
}
```

And this is my table structure:

[image]

And finally my question , when I call `UserManager.CreateAsync(NewUser)` a user is correctly created, however when I try to add the newly created user to a role for example the admin role like so `await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(NewUser, "Admin");` it does not throw any error, but what happens is it creates a new user with null user name, first name etc and it adds a new role to the roles table with a null Name and null normalized name. Then it adds that role to the `UserRoles` table. All without any errors.

According to MS Documentation this should create one new user and add that user to the Admin role. Docs I built this from are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Can you post the register component which using this method? These functions work well in my project.

Comment: Please use a title that describes the problem. Used technologies should be avoided in titles because they're clear from tags.

Comment: I fixed to better match my question! And I accepted my own answer! Thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging today I figured out what was going on. Have a look at my `AppUserRole` class

```
public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRole Role { get; set; }
    public AppUserRole()
    {
        User = new AppUser();
        Role = new AppRole();
    }
}
```

Since I was newing up a new `AppUser()` and a new `AppRole()` they in turn were calling the base class constructors in which `IdentityRole` sets its `Id` property to a new `Guid` the same thing happens when the constructor of `IdentityUser` is called. I found that out by looking at the `AspNetCore.Identity` source code. So EntityFramework was correctly doing its job, it saw a brand new `AppUserRole` with a new `IdentityUser` and new `IdentityRole` and since these were navigation properties to `AppRole` it created them in the database.

**TLDR**  The fix was to make the navigation properties in the `AppUserRole` class nullable and not new them up in the constructor as in below:

```
public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual AppUser? User { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRole? Role { get; set; }
    public AppUserRole()
    {
        
    }
}
```